# How do you get your prompt back after executing a command like systemctl on linux?

Tags: prompt

Real noob question:
I was running a script on Linux- systemctl and I want to search for a specific file but before I can type in the new code | grep 'filenames I need to get the prompt back but am unable to do so, I have tried using the space bar along with a few other commands but nothing seems to work. Is there anyway for me to get this back without ending the process?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Posting the complete command might help. Might it be that you want to run a command in the background? You can type an ampersand (&) at the end of it for that. Like `mplayer myaudiofile.mp3 &` and the prompt will be available for a new command while the computer still plays the music.

Comment: Press `q`. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: We definitely need more information here. `systemctl` looks at services, not at file names. Are you running a script within your service file? Can we see what the script contains?